# How to write two comma seperated values as one value

Tags: java, csv

I am retrieving the values using regular expression in jmeter and writing those values into a csv file.But one of my value returns values as (value1,value2), how can i add write those 2 values as one value in csv file.Below is my code

```
String statusvar = vars.get("guid");
String guidstat = vars.get("guidn");
String custstat = vars.get("custType");


String fpath = vars.get("write_file_path");

String newStatus;

 FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(fpath+"new_record.csv", false);

 BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);


 out.write(statusvar+","+guidstat+","+custstat);
 out.newLine();
 out.flush();
```

Comment: I'm not sure, if I understand your problem correctly. Assuming, that one of `statusvar`, `guidstat` or `custstat` contains a value like `"(foo,bar)"` and you want to put that value into one column of your csv, you can just use quotes, e.g. `String line = "\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\"";
out.write(String.format(line, statusvar, guidstat, custstat );`

Comment: yes, you are right.custstat value sometime returns value as foo and sometime foo,bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your values within quotes and it should be OK. If a value contains quotes, then you'd need to escape them. Just replace each `"` by `""`, so `value"a,valueB` is written as `"value""a,valueB"`

If this becomes too tricky then I suggest getting a CSV parsing/writing library to do the job for you such as [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) - I'm the author of this one by the way.